# How do i create date specific folders in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am naive in linux and looking for a guidance in one of the scripts I am developing

I have a path:

> /data/mm/ms

I want to generate a script to create date specific folder for each day inside the above path.
Here is what I have created but is incomplete

```
dir= dd/mm/ms                       //Existing directory
DIR_DATE=$(`date +%Y%m%d`)          //todays date stored inside a variable   
CREATE_DIR= mkdir $dir/$DIR_DATE      // want to create a date specific dir inside $dir
```

But the following code does not work, can you help me out how can I get a result like:

dd/mm/ms/20140211

dd/mm/ms/20140212

and so on..

I realise the code on line 3

```
CREATE_DIR= mkdir $dir/$DIR_DATE
```

is not correct and I need to change that, but not sure how

---

I have updated my code see below:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir= "/data/mvr/MasterFiles/testing"
DIR_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d) 
CREATE_DIR="${dir}/${DIR_DATE}"
mkdir "${CREATE_DIR}" || echo "Error creating directory ${CREATE_DIR}"
```

I reiterate my question, I want to create date specific folder inside an existing directory

> Existing directory: /data/mm/ms

Need to create date specific folders for each day inside this existing folder path

> eg /data/mm/ms/20140211
>
> /data/mm/ms/20140212
>
> and so on

Comment: ok, and your question is what?

Comment: do you want something like `mkdir -p $(date +%Y%m%d)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to Command Substitution:

```
dir="/data/mm/ms"
DIR_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
CREATE_DIR="${dir}/${DIR_DATE}"
mkdir "${CREATE_DIR}" || echo "Error creating directory ${CREATE_DIR}"
```

Saying:

```
var= value
```

would attempt to execute the command `value` with the variable `var` unset.

Additionally, you use the form `$(command)` for command substitution; backticks is another way.  You seem to have combined the two.  That is another error.

Comment: oh right i understand what you did in the above code but did not quite understand this var= value

Comment: Use mkdir -p "${CREATE_DIR}" and an error won't be produced if the directory already exists.

Comment: @Rahulsawant That refers to `dir= dd/mm/ms`.  I'm certain you'd have received an error for that line too.

Comment: after using the above it gives me an error saying :./testing: line 4: /data/mm/ms: is a directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `/20140211': Permission denied

Comment: @Rahulsawant Did you say `dir= /data/mm/ms` in your script?  Do you have permissions to create a directory in the given path?

Comment: @devnull : i understand now what you say, i did change my code but i am still getting the above error

Comment: @Rahulsawant Post the modified code in your question.  Don't edit the previous one; add the new one.

Comment: @devnull : `dir= /data/mm/ms `is an existing directory under which we want to create date specific folders. Yes i do have access to the folder. i even tried creating a normal folder in it and it allowed me to. its just that this script wont work

Comment: @Rahulsawant You didn't read the answer, did you?  Putting a space before or after `=` while assigning a variable wouldn't work.

Comment: @devnull: I did not realize you were talking about the space, i did understand what you said though and now its crystal clear :)  i tried again after ur suggestion and it works just fine. I appreciate your help and concern towards me Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're on the right track. This might work better:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=/data/mm/ss
DIR_DATE=`date +%Y%m%d` # not sure on the Y, m, and d -- check man pages

mkdir ${dir}/${DIR_DATE}

# check exit code
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   # error! print something to the user
   exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: after using the above it gives me an error saying :./testing: line 4: /data/mm/ms: is a directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `/20140211': Permission denied

Comment: any idea why cause I do have permission to the folder

Comment: Try changing to something like this:  mkdir "${dir}/${DIR_DATE}"  Also try printing it out. I wonder if there's a space somewhere in the path.

Comment: Can you provide a long directory listing? Are you sure you have permission **and** are the owner?  ls -la /data/mvr/MasterFiles/testing

Comment: well what you said works fine it was my mistake  in my code i added a space between dir= /data/mm/ms due to which it was assigning a value to a variable which is not set. But it works now having edited my blunder